# Imprimir templates con ternarios en coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

Cómo puedo imprimir operadores ternarios junto con *string templates* usando coffescript?

Si ejecuto el código como:

```
peopleWithAgeDrink = (old)->
  "drink "+"#{`old<14?'toddy':old<18?'coke':old<21?'beer':'whisky'`}"
```

obtengo el resultado deseado, pero

```
peopleWithAgeDrink = (old)->
  "drink #{`old<14?'toddy':old<18?'coke':old<21?'beer':'whisky'`}"
```

da resultados erroneos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres utilizar el operador ternario (o condicional):

```
peopleWithAgeDrink = (old)->
  "drink #{if old < 14 then 'toddy' else if old < 18 then 'coke' else if old < 21 then 'beer' else 'whisky'}"
```

El operador condicional en CoffeeScript sigue la forma de

```
if <condición> then <valor1> else <valor2>
```

Pero no te recomendaría escribir múltiples condiciones seguidas de esta manera.

Además estás usando el símbolo `` ` `` (acento grave o *backtick*) en el *template*.  Este símbolo no es para *strings*, lo que hace es indicar a CoffeeScript que lo que esté encerrado entre `` ` ` `` debe interpretarlo como JavaScript regular y no traducirlo.  Esto tiene usos válidos pero te recomiendo que no lo utilices hasta que estés bastante familiarizado con CoffeeScript.

Otra forma más idiomática en de escribir esto en CoffeeScript sería:

```
peopleWithAgeDrink = (old) ->
    "drink #{
        switch
          when old < 14 then 'toddy'
          when old < 18 then 'coke'
          when old < 21 then 'beer'
          else 'whisky'
    }"
```

---

Ahora si es que ya entiendes los problemas de mezclar JavaScript con Coffeescript y aun así quieres hacerlo de esa manera:

**No recomendado**

```
peopleWithAgeDrink = (old)->
  "drink #{`(old<14?'toddy':old<18?'coke':old<21?'beer':'whisky')`}"
```

Lo que le faltaba al código eran paréntesis para que evaluara en el orden correcto la expresión.

Comment: Gracias, el if then else no es un ternario por definición :P